# PHP Array and HTML Form Drop Down List

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a simple PHP Array called $categories that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[Closed] => P1000
[Open] => P1001
[Pending] => P1002
[In Progress] => P1003
[Requires Approval] => P1004
)
```

I've got a simple HTML form that has a drop down list for one field that I would like to use the array for the options, however I only want it do show the text (e.g. Closed, Open, Pending, In Progress and Requires Approval) as the options in the drop down list but store the associated key for that option (e.g. P1000, P1001 etc) which is then sent as a POST value when the form is submitted.

The HTML for the form field so far is:

```
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php foreach($categories as $category) {$category = htmlspecialchars($category);?>
<option value="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $category; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

I can get it to display either the text or the ID's but not the text and store the ID. Hopefully this is something simple that someone can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've forgot about $value tag. You were pasting Category name twice, instead of value. You should do that:

```
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php 
    #                             !vCHANGEv!
    foreach($categories as $category => $value) 
    {
       $category = htmlspecialchars($category); 
       echo '<option value="'. $value .'">'. $category .'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Robik and everyone else who pointed out the same thing - was not getting the key for each value in the array. Everything is working great now. Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

As you have to include key and value both key is to show the text and value for POST

```
<?php foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
   $category = htmlspecialchars($category);?>
   <option value="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $key; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not included keys in foreach loop

```
foreach($categories as $id=>$category){
    $category = htmlspecialchars($category);
    echo "<option value="{$id}">{$category}</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($categories as $category => $category_id)
```

Is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$keys = array_keys($categories);
for($i=0; $i<count($categories); $i++)
{?>
    <option value="<?php echo $keys[$i]; ?>"><?php echo $categories[$i]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Supposing that $categories is the array you have shown above.